# Insert list with several items into mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, database, list

I have a list like this:

```
list = [('name1', 'id1', 'created_at1'),('name2', 'id2', 'created_at2'),('name3', 'id3', 'created_at3')]
```

And I want to put it into a Mysql Database using MySQLdb that it looks like this in the end:

```
Name   ID    Created_at
name1  id1   created_at1
name2  id2   created_at2
name3  id3   created_at3
```

I tried something like:

```
for s in list:
   var_string = ', '.join('?' * len(s))
   query_string = 'INSERT INTO TweetsTest VALUES (%s);' % s
   cursor.execute(query_string, varlist)
```

But it does not work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: also, define 'does not work'

Comment: what is var_string that you are not using, and what is varlist supposed to be? you should invert the use of s and varlist/var_string

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO TweetsTest "
       "(Name, ID, Created_at) VALUES ")

for item in list:
    sqlRow = "('%s', '{1}', '{2}'), ".format(item[1], item[2]) % item[0]
    sql += sqlRow

sql = sql[:-2] + ";"
cursors.execute(sql)
```

All the above is implying that those 3 fields are all string based, thus the quotes in the `for` loop. For all numeric fields - remove the quotes.

Comment: Gives me the following error: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Well then your list is not `list = [('name1', 'id1', 'created_at1')]` as you provided in your question. @user2401772 and by the way, you can actually debug this kind of error yourself, just `print item` in the for loop and see what you get.